# How to insert a record in userterritory object

Tags: apex, rest-api, soap-api

There is a field on Account and same on User object for exp field is DC and value can be DC1, DC2 etc.and on that basis, I created the territories named DC1 and DC2

These value can be changed on both the object as Account can move automatiaclly among all the territories but we also need to move user records.
And we need to do it automatically(through Apex) but DML is not allowed in Uerterritory object.

Any solution through SOAP or Rest API??

Can anyone help me on this.
This will be highly appreaciable

Comment: `Create` & `Delete` methods are available on `UserTerritory` Object. You can check here for info https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_userterritory.htm

Comment: Yes Create & Delete available but not using Apex. we have to use SOAP API or Rest API and REST API is not supporting bulk process so I need some help in SOAP API snippet